# Merge two table based on column on the table in java MYSQL

Tags: java, sql, arrays, arraylist

Hye, I want to ask regarding the java and MYSQL problems.

For example I have 2 tables which is department and duty:

1.Department:

| Dept_id | exp_id |
| --- | --- |
| dept_1 | exp_1 |
| dept_2 | exp_1 |
| dept_1 | exp_2 |
| dept_2 | exp_2 |

2. Duty :

| Duty_id | exp_id |
| --- | --- |
| duty_1 | exp_1 |
| duty_2 | exp_1 |
| duty_3 | exp_1 |
| duty_4 | exp_2 |
| duty_5 | exp_2 |
| duty_6 | exp_2 |
| duty_7 | exp_2 |

I need to merge this two table without duplication and distributed equally. After that, I need to insert the data into new table called result. The foreign keys of these two tables is exp_id.

result table:

| Duty_id | Dept_id |
| --- | --- |
| duty_1 | dept_1 |
| duty_2 | dept_2 |
| duty_3 | dept_1 |
| duty_4 | dept_1 |
| duty_5 | dept_2 |
| duty_6 | dept_1 |
| duty_7 | dept_2 |

Comment: Why would Duty 4 relate to Dept 1? Your data is confusing as is your Question.

Comment: Better formatting of your example data would improve this Question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I have changed the question using SQL table. I think it is easier to understand with this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row_number items within exp_id and match positions

```
select du.duty_id, dp.Dept_id
from (
   select Dept_id, exp_id, row_number() over(partition by exp_id order by Dept_id) rn , count(Dept_id) over(partition by exp_id ) cnt
   from Department
   ) dp
join (
   select Duty_id, exp_id,  row_number() over(partition by exp_id order by Duty_id) rn
   from Duty
   ) du 
   on dp.exp_id = du.exp_id and (du.rn - 1) % dp.cnt  + 1 = dp.rn
order by du.duty_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=628a09a757d4a191f948352aad202350)

Comment: I have a question if this query is correct in MySQL? i try to run on on query tab in MySQL, However, it seems that Line 3 got SQL Error.

Comment: It will run ok in MySql 8.0, see the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

guess, result table is already created with appropriate data types. You would need to use some SQL query as below:

```
INSERT INTO RESULT(Duty_id, Dept_id)
SELECT duty.Duty_id, dept.Dept_id FROM Department dept, Duty duty where dept.exp_id=duty.exp_id;
```